# Передача данных из Fragment в Activity

Tags: android, android-fragment

Добрый день. Каким образом передаются данные (надо строку передать) из `Fragment` в `Activity`?

Нашел в документации [вот что](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)

Может есть другие способы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У любого фрагмента всегда (почти) есть ссылка на хостовую `Activity`. Получить эту ссылку можно при помощи `getActivity();`
Предположим, что класс вашей хостовой `Activity` называется `MyActivity`. Обьявите в ней какой-то `public` метод, например так:

```
public void dataFromFragment(String data) {
//тут делайте что хотите с data
}
```

И теперь во фрагменте:

```
if(getActivity() != null) {
    String data = "ура, у нас есть какие-то данные для отправки в активити!"
    ((MyActivity)getActivity).dataFromFragment(data);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, так и сделал

Comment: Ссылка появляется сразу после метода onAttach(Activity activity)